# Linear algebra: Show that there exists vectors $c_i \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $A\cdot c_i=b_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_{m,n} (\mathbb R)$ be a real matrix of rank $r=n$. Let $(b_1,b_2,..,b_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for the column space $R(A)$ (terms. the scalar product)

- Show that for each $i=1,2,...,n$, there exists a vector $c_i \in \mathbb R^n$, such that $A\cdot c_i=b_i$.

Now since I need to show this for all i, would it then make sense for me to make an induction proof? And if so, how could i do this?

Comment: If $\operatorname{rk} A = n$, then ${\cal R} A = \mathbb{R}^n$, hence for any $b$ there is some $x$ such that $Ax = b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix has full column rank.

So, let us start with $A x = b$ for any $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and see if we can solve for $x$. Then, left multiply by $A^T$ to get $(A^T A) x = A^T b$. Since $A$ had full column rank, $A^T A$ is a full rank square matrix so is invertible. Thus, $x= (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$ is a solution to the system $A x = b$.